# Perfect fractional matching of uniform hyper graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, matching

Are there necessary and sufficient conditions for a uniform hyper graph to have a perfect fractional matching ?

Comment: The definition is already a nice characterization. What are you looking for? A necessary and sufficient condition that is combinatorial?

Comment: Could you provide some context, background, and motivation?

Comment: To me it seem that if you can solve the problem quickly in uniform hypergraphs, you can also solve the problem quickly in arbitrary hypergraphs – just add gadgets that make the hypergraph uniform while preserving the existence of a perfect fractional matching. And in the case of arbitrary hypergraphs, it seems to me that the problem is almost as difficult as solving a general 0/1 packing LP. Hence I would not expect that there is a particularly useful formulation of a necessary & sufficient condition.

Comment: 1. Yes, combinatorial condition, like Tuttes's theorem
2. No it is not like 1/0, because for ex. regular graph has perfect fractional matching,
but very few is known about 1/0 problem for it.